# which approach is faster: wcf auto generated proxy or channelfactory<t> for consuming services

Tags: c#, wcf

i have created a wcf service and wanted to consume it in the client application.  performance wise, which is better? auto generated classes which are added by service reference or the channelfactory way?

Answer (score 5):

If you step through the auto generated proxy code, you will see that this code uses the ChannelFactory mechanism anyway.

So my answer: the performance is identical.

The only potential difference could be in the code you write around the ChannelFactory calls, which, when compared with the ensuing network call, is effectively zero.